# Can't figure out of how to stop the application when a specific String value match a specific condition

Tags: java

It's my first time posting some topic on this website, and running on a problem that I can't get over it. The following problem that I'm stunning into is as followed:

When the total calculation of the above decimal numbers meets a specific target amount, print: "Congratulations" if not, print:"Calculation error", after they input the string word: "Ready". when a user inputs a string called: "I Quit!", the application will exit and prints: "Quitter".

Here is the Java code that I currently have:

```
public static void goal(double targetAmount) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    double total = 0;

    while (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
        double input= sc.nextDouble();
        total += input;
    }


    String inputString = sc.next();     
}
```

I'm looking forward to see your response. Hope I've formulate my question properly?

Comment: OK, you've explained the problem you are trying to solve (good), and you'e showed the code you wrote to solve it (also good), and the results you were expecting to see (again, good).  But you forgot to tell us what difficulty you are having: that is, how did your solution fail to live up to expectations?

Comment: First of all thanks for your response. Sorry that I didn't have told my expectations and difficulties. My difficulty is when I use the statement 'input = scanner.nextLine()', it only takes the first condition of the switch statement that has a space separation in between (see: "I Quit!") and not the single word (text) (see: "Ready"). And when I use the statement input = scanner.next(), it ignore the first condition of the switch statement. I've already replaced the space of the "I Quit!" condition with an underscore (see other replies). But that doesn't match the condition.

Comment: When you read your input with `nextLine()`, it's possible that `input` will include some leading and/or trailing blank spaces, which would cause it not to match with your `switch` cases.  Try `input = nextLine().trim();` instead ([Javadoc for  `trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) to remove those extra spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the `input` you read using `scanner.next()`, because `scanner.next()` **reads the input till the next blank character**. Which means it will just read `I` when you enter `I Quit!`.

Printing the output of the variable `input` shows the problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    salarisdoel(100);
}

public static void salarisdoel(double targetAmount) {
    Scanner scanner= new Scanner(System.in);

    double total = 0;

    while (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
        double inputMoney= scanner.nextDouble();
        total += inputMoney;
    }


    String input = scanner.next();
    System.out.println(input);//print to check what was read from the console
    switch (input) {
        case "I Quit!":
            System.out.println("Quitter");
            break;
        case "Ready":
            if (total>= targetAmount) {
                System.out.println("Congratulations");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Calculation Error");
            }
            break;
        default: 
            System.out.println("Something went wrong. Try again!");
            break;
    }     
}
```

If you use a string without a blank space for quitting (e.g. `"I_Quit!"`) it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried your solution and came up with an extra input.nextLine() statement in the while-loop.  And also changed the statement: 'String input = scanner.next()' to 'String input = scanner.nextLine()'. I've run the application and did exactly what I've been wanted. I don't know if it is handy/efficient way to do that. But thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `System.exit()` to exit the program.

```java
 case "I Quit!":
   System.out.println("Quitter");
   System.exit();
```